# Azure learning studio Chat bot with authenticated URL as source

Tags: chatbot, azure-cognitive-services, azure-bot-service, language-studio

I am creating a azure cognitive service chatbot where I am currently adding static URLs as sources. Is there any option to add a URL as source to questions and answers section where the URL is authenticated via azure active directory authentiation?

Steps Followed:

```
1. Navigate to Azure portal
    2. Search for "Language"
    3. Select Create
    4. Custom Question Answering
    5. Create resource
    6. Login to Language studio - Language.cognitive.azure.com
    7. Manage sources

 8. Add URL (I am adding non authenticated URL as of now).
```

How can I add a authenticated URL as source for custom Questions and Answers in Language studio

Answer (score 0):

You can authenticate the request through the native **Azure Cognitive Auth** with Azure AAD: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/authentication?tabs=powershell#authenticate-with-azure-active-directory

Hopefully this is something that you're looking for.

Comment: I am looking for something where I can import and read an authenticated URL to custom question and answering chatbot.